# Slow USB reading operation

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I got an Arduino UNO today, and I am just writing a basic blink program. I have 3 LEDS on the arduino. Those LEDS are connected to Pin 1, 2, and 3.

Now I can control those LED by writing octal values 0 to 7 to the `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

The code I have written so far is:

```
# pragma GCC optimize ("Ofast")

# define LED1 1
# define LED2 2
# define LED3 3

char buf[4] ;
unsigned char inp, len ;

void setup() {
    pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT) ;
    pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT) ;
    pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT) ;
    
    Serial.begin(9600) ;
}

void loop() {
    len = Serial.readBytes(buf, 3) ;
            
    if (len) {
        buf[3] = '\0' ;
        inp = atoi(buf) ;

        // Illuminate LEDs
        digitalWrite(LED1, 1 & inp ? HIGH : LOW) ;
        digitalWrite(LED2, 2 & inp ? HIGH : LOW) ;
        digitalWrite(LED3, 4 & inp ? HIGH : LOW) ;
    }
}
```

So when I write:

- 0 turns off all the LEDS
- 1 turns on LED on pin 1
- 2 turns on LED on pin 2
- 3 turns on LED on pin 1 and 2
- 4 turns on LED on pin 3
- 5 turns on LED on pin 1 and 3
- 6 turns on LED on pin 2 and 3
- 7 turns on all the LEDS.

The problem is that, when I write 7 for example, it takes up to 1 second to turn on the LEDS. If I write 0, it takes another second to turn off the LEDS.

Is there way to control the LEDS in close to real-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending multiple bytes which together form a single message it is best to use a delimiter character and read the data until there. That way you don't run into timeouts and you can be sure, that the received data represents a full message.

In the cases where the LEDs need 1s to react you are most likely sending less than 3 bytes, which causes the `Serial.readBytes()` function to time out after the default 1s. I guess you are currently always sending only 1 byte (though you are trying to read 3 byte in your code).

To use a delimiter character there are multiple ways. The easiest fix would be using `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')`. The newline character (which I used as a parameter here) is a common delimiter character. You would then need to aways send the newline character at the end of a full message.

Just setting the timeout very low is not a very good solution. With a low baudrate as 9600 that can easily mean, that the message is chopped up into multiple parts, because the transmission takes longer than the timeout.

---

Besides that: I don't really understand, why you need to receive 3 bytes for turning on or off 3 LEDs. One byte (even, when you are just using single digits) has a big enough data space for more than these 3 LEDs. Also you are not really using octal numbers. `atoi()` is expecting a string representation of a decimal number. There is nothing octal in your code. And then you are using the first 3 bits of the resulting number for controlling the LEDs.

All in all this seems quite complicated for a very basic task. Maybe there is some reason for that, which you didn't write about.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Serial.readBytes()` when there may or may not be 3 bytes available. If there aren't 3, the call waits for them to arrive or for a timeout. That's the delay you are seeing.

If you really want 3 bytes at a time, check whether there are 3 before you try to read them:

```
if( Serial.available >= 3 )
   len = Serial.readBytes(buf, 3);
```

When the `if` fails - because there aren't three bytes available - you won't waste any time waiting for them.

Answer (score 0):

On the Arduino UNO pins 0 and 1 are used for serial communications.  That might not make a difference here, but it's probably a good idea to avoid them unless really needed.

Comment: This should be a comment